# Pytorch LSTM predicts too low values

Tags: python, pandas, neural-network, pytorch

I followed the guide on https://stackabuse.com/time-series-prediction-using-lstm-with-pytorch-in-python/ in order to set up a LSTM model for predictions using torch.
Once imported the needed modules (torch, torch.nn, functional, optim, etc:) I set up my indexlist with quantities for 52 weeks.

```
idxlist = []

for x in range (0, len(inputslist)):
    idxlist.append(a - datetime.timedelta(weeks = x))

in_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date','qty'])
in_data.date = idxlist
in_data.qty = inputslist
all_data = in_data['qty'].values.astype(float)
```

Then, I defined the test size and set up a scaler to normalize data:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))
train_data_normalized = scaler.fit_transform(train_data.reshape(-1,1))
train_data_normalized = torch.FloatTensor(train_data_normalized).view(-1)
#train window
train_window = 12
```

Then I created sequences:

```python
def create_inout_sequences(input_data,tw):
    inout_seq = []
    L = len(input_data) ##40
    for i in range(L-tw): ##32 (se tw=8)
        train_seq = input_data[i:i+tw]
        train_label = input_data[i+tw:i+tw+1]
        inout_seq.append((train_seq ,train_label))
    return inout_seq

train_inout_seq = create_inout_sequences(train_data_normalized, train_window)
print(len(train_inout_seq)) #len(train) - train_w
```

And set up the Net class for the LSTM model. After optimizing with model=LSTM(), optim.Adam and model.eval(), I obtain the inverse transform with:

```
actual_predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(np.array(test_inputs[train_window:] ).reshape(-1, 1))
```

However, plotting the predicted values of last 12 weeks with the actual values I obtain:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTHgS.png).

Why is this prediction so much below the actual values, even if periodic?

Comment: Did the training converge? What's the final loss?

Comment: I think so.. in the end the loss was 0.00149374, calculated with the MSELoss function.

Comment: I changed the hidden layer size from 100 to 200, and now the prediction is higher than expected.. Any reasons for this?

Comment: Try to train it longer, e.g. 300 epochs. There might be a difference.